# Parsing XML using etree in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have looked at the documentation and other similar questions and can't work out what's going wrong here!

I want to use the XML output from an API.

I have XML that looks a bit like this:

```
<response>
<lst></lst>
<result>
    <doc>
        <str name ="pa">1234</str>
        <str name ="et">Title 1</str>
        <str name ="pb">Publisher 1</str>
        <str name ="ur">http://www.exampleone.com</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <str name ="pa">5678</str>
        <str name ="et">Title 2</str>
        <str name ="pb">Publisher 2</str>
        <str name ="ur">http://www.exampletwo.com</str>
    </doc>
</result>
```

I want to get the "pa" for each doc element.

This is the code I am using, but get nothing:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get("api url goes here")

tree = ET.fromstring(r.content)

for doc in tree.findall("doc"):
    pan = doc.find('pa').text
    print pan
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

resp = '''<response><lst></lst><result><doc>
            <str name ="pa">1234</str>
            <str name ="et">Title 1</str>
            <str name ="pb">Publisher 1</str>
            <str name ="ur">http://www.exampleone.com</str>
          </doc>
          <doc>
            <str name ="pa">5678</str>
            <str name ="et">Title 2</str>
            <str name ="pb">Publisher 2</str>
            <str name ="ur">http://www.exampletwo.com</str>
          </doc></result></response>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(resp)

for pan in tree.findall('.//str[@name="pa"]'):
    print(pan.text)
```

With your code, it needs minor changes to work:

Either:

```
for doc in tree[1].findall("doc"):
    pan = doc.find('str[@name="pa"]').text
    print (pan)
```

Or

```
for doc in tree.findall(".//doc"):
    pan = doc.find('str[@name="pa"]').text
    print (pan)
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the second example you gave and it produced the result I was after.

Answer (score 3):

`doc.find('pa')` would search for the *`pa` element*, which doesn't exist.

Instead, you need to look for *`str` element with `name` attribute* equal to `pa`:

```
doc.find('.//str[@name="pa"]')
```

Demo:

```
>>> for doc in tree.findall("doc"):
...     pan = doc.find('.//str[@name="pa"]').text
...     print pan
... 
1234
5678
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I tried this before. I have tried it again and I still don't get any results.

Comment: @Abbie well, it worked for me using the provided example. I suspect the XML you've provided is not what you actually get from the API request.

Comment: In the xml sample that you provided in your question, you are missing a `</response>` at the end.

Comment: @rparent if it'd be really missing, it would result into an error while parsing the XML thrown by elementtree.

Comment: My guess it's either a different response retrieved from the API endpoint, or there are namespaces defined.

Comment: You're right. To make the whole thing work, just work on `tree = ET.fromstring(r.content).getroot()` to get an ElementTree instead of an Element.